# How to get values given the key value in a set in SharedPreferences in Android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

```
public void buttonClick(View v)
{
    EditText sd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sd);
    EditText desc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.description);
    Spinner type = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.type);
    Spinner priority = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.priority);
    Set<String> set = new HashSet();

    if(!validate(sd))
        sd.setError("This field cannot be empty");
    else if(!validate(desc))
        desc.setError("This field cannot be empty");
    else
    {
        set.add(type.getSelectedItem().toString());
        set.add(priority.getSelectedItem().toString());
        set.add(desc.getText().toString());

        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putStringSet(sd.getText().toString(),set);
        editor.commit();
        Log.d("MyTag",pref.getAll().toString());

        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

private boolean validate(EditText t1)
{
    if(t1.getText().length()==0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Here in the above code, I am storing the details in the SharedPreferences with StringSet. The key is `sd` string and the values are `desc`, `type` and `priority'. I created a Set and put the key and the corresponding values in the set. How do I fetch the values for a given key?

The method `pref.getStringSet(key, Set<String>)` expects both key and the values. The key value is known but what should be put in the second argument? Tried `null` but it expects a type of Set.

Comment: have you seen my answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go ahead and put `null` there. The following compiles and works for me:

```
HashSet<String> hashSet = hashSet = (HashSet<String>) sp.getStringSet("names", null);
```

The second value is the default value. If `Lint` gives you an error when you put `null`, just tell `Lint` to ignore that error.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter in `pref.getStringSet(key, Set<String>)` is a default value in case the preference has never been set before.

Check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29):

**Parameters**

- `key`     The name of the preference to retrieve.
- `defValues`  Values to return if this preference does not exist.

So if it has already been set, the previously assigned value is returned. Otherwise `defValues` is returned.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument is a default value, if the shared preference you try to get doesn't exist or, you put a wrong name as first argument it will be set to the default value passed as second argument.

The key value is a label wich you will use to get that specific shared preference, for example:

`editor.putString("name_of_your_preference", value_of_preference);`

and then you could retrieve that string with:

```
pref.getString("name_of_your_preference", default_value);
```

you could use NULL only as default value